# Tense question on stative verb

Tags: verbs

Can present continuos tense take stative verb?

Such as i am thinking about him now.

I am loving the food now.
Please give the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that "think" and "love" are stative verbs, and so you are asking whether those verbs may be used in the present continuous tense? These verbs may be used in that tense, but I don't believe these verbs are stative.

"know" is a stative verb, and that cannot be used in the present continuous. "I am knowing" is not grammatical.